# Fill rows with help datatable from MSSQL Server

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have created a table without a binding source, and I want to view rows from a table in a database located in MYSQL. This code will create a table and connect to the DataGridView:

```
public void DynamicallyTable()
        {
            // create table dynamically
            dt = new DataTable();
            // add column name
            dt.Columns.Add(COLUMN1, typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add(COLUMN2, typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add(COLUMN3, typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add(COLUMN4, typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add(COLUMN5, typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add(COLUMN6, typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add(COLUMN7, typeof(int));

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
```

This record is in the Form_Load code and how to make work with the foreign keys in DataGridView? The problem is, to display the values of lines without an adapter, for example, fill lines in DataGridView and work with the foreign key. Please can you help me and thank you for your answers!

I found other way for view in datagridview where error: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to Int64:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                connection.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@hut", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 4;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@spisanie_id", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = IDtextBox.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@prichanie_spis", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = PrichinatextBox.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@data_spis", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dateEdit.Text;
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); //this error shows here
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add((string)rdr["Prichina"], (string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", rdr["data"])));                   
                }
```

I can use that way but program error: "Don't correct output format"

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@hut", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters["@hut"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmd.Parameters["@hut"].Value = 4;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@spisanie_id", SqlDbType.BigInt);
            cmd.Parameters["@spisanie_id"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmd.Parameters["@spisanie_id"].Value = Convert.ToInt64(IDtextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@prichanie_spis", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["@prichanie_spis"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmd.Parameters["@prichanie_spis"].Value = PrichinatextBox.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@data_spis", SqlDbType.Date);
            cmd.Parameters["@data_spis"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmd.Parameters["@data_spis"].Value = dateEdit.Value.Date;
```

I found way and shared with your:

```
    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.sp_test", connection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    connection.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@taw", SqlDbType.Int);
    cmd.Parameters["@taw"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    cmd.Parameters["@taw"].Value = 4;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@value", SqlDbType.BigInt);
    cmd.Parameters["@value"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    cmd.Parameters["@value"].Value = DBNull.Value;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@value1", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    cmd.Parameters["@value1"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    cmd.Parameters["@value1"].Value = DBNull.Value;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@value2", SqlDbType.Date);
    cmd.Parameters["@value2"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    cmd.Parameters["@value2"].Value = DBNull.Value;
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(rdr["your_column"].ToString(), (string)rdr["your_column1"].ToString(), (string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", rdr["your_column"])).ToString());                   
    }
    connection.Close();
```

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but can you try to find someone with better English skills who could help you to translate your question? I can't understand what you are trying to ask.

Comment: Is that MySql or SqlServer? they are 2 different products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Parse()` for certain parameters:

```
  ...
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@spisanie_id", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = BigInteger.Parse(IDtextBox.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@prichanie_spis", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = PrichinatextBox.Text;
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@data_spis", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Parse(dateEdit.Text);
    ...
```